# Additional Processing Required in Registration for a Devise Login System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, authorization

I have this registration form which requires more processing than adding username, password and email unto the Devise Model "Access" or what is commonly referred to as "user"; things like addresses, contact details and telephone numbers.

How do I make devise run these methods for additional processing for adding into other models?

I keep seeing a RegistrationController; SessionController but I can't find any proper documentation on usage; am I missing a good resource other than the one on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite configure_permitted_parameters of devise controller in application controller like this:-

```
# Application Controller:
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username,  :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
end
```

And we you want to add some attributes in other model(table) then you can add by doing this:-

```
Suppose you have has_one association of user with profile model:
# User model:
has_one :profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

#Profile model:
belongs_to :user
```

Then configure_permitted_parameters method will look like this:-

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username,  :email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:phone_number, :address, :contact]) }
end
```

Hope this may helpful!!